# Centos5 ]Using other user's python

Tags: python, python-import, centos5

I'm now trying to use python installed in other user's account.

Cause I can't use python installed in my account.

Other user's python exists in the other_user/bin directory account.
And I also installed numpy in other user's account.

Numpy and matplotlib works in the other user's account

If I type

```
~/../other_user/bin/python2.7
```

Ok. it works.

However,

If I type,

```
import numpy
```

then

```
No module named numpy
```

I think, if I change

```
import numpy
```

to other command or If I set some path option, it is possible to use other user's python.

Is there any method?

Comment: Compare `sys.path` from the 2 accounts. How was numpy installed in the other account? Have you considered using virtualenvs?

Comment: Why can't you use it on your own account? Given that you're having issues with the other account, it might make more sense to troubleshoot the problem with Python on your account

Comment: @Wooble : I made another account and Installed numpy in the new account's home directory using new account. Virtualenv? How can it solve the prblem?

Comment: @StephenTG  I'm using centOS 5 and I tried to upgrade python version 2.4 to 2.7 and it destroyed python.. I tried to fix that problem it is too difficult to me. So I choose alternative way 'making new account to use python'